# Is the London system a good chess opening for beginners?

Tags: opening, london-system

Is the London System opening is a good opening to invest on for getting deep on its variation for a beginner player (rank 1000-1100)? actually I heard it's a boring and systemical opening and for example **GM Hikaru** doesn't like this opening (I see his reactions on his stream when someone plays it), although I saw some amazing game that **Magnus Carlsen** played with London System.

Comment: Before posting a question it is a good idea to use the search function to see if similar questions have already been asked. In this case there have been several such. Check out this one for instance - https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/29103/why-does-the-london-system-have-the-reputation-it-has

Comment: But at the same time Hikaru does teach Fuslie, a complete beginner, London system. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHeqpdqbsqg

Comment: @BrianTowers the question title it's not even the same as this question and of course can not be found with searching about London system easily

Comment: beginner at 1000-1100 have to invest time in learning chess instead of studying specific opening - that level really requires solving puzzles and learning endgames, mating technique.

Answer (score 3):

It depends.
Any system (almost) can be good/bad for you/your_opponent depending on many factors.

You should pick one opening you like that fits your personality/style of play.  And then master that opening.  Be prepared to change as you improve though as what worked against beginners may not be as good against masters and GMs

Answer (score 2):

Your question asks for opinions, which isn't correct form. So it'll be closed or you'll be asked to re-frame it, something like that.

My opinion is no, and beginners shouldn't worry about openings or what GMs think of openings. Learn tactics and endings.

Comment: actually I do not agree with you, this is not an opinion based question, as I saw in questions, the same idea question appeared to be very well received, such as what is simple openings and what is aggressive openings, those are opinion based as you said, so I'm not looking for ideas here, I'm looking for tips here, and with naming GMs I meant it's not clear it is good or not. _learn tactics and endings_ also work for any level player not just for beginners (sure I should learn more about them) but it's not the context here.

Comment: Where inexpert players are concerned, the London System is to 1. d4 as the Four Knights Game is to 1. e4. The Four Knights isn't good for inexpert players because they don't know how to open a position following a tame opening. The London isn't good for inexpert players because they don't know what to do with that prematurely-developed bishop. I just wrote a piece about bad chess teachers recommending the London: https://www.facebook.com/friscodelrosario/posts/10158892785067853